# Exporting and importing subversion revisions using svn clients

Tags: svn

I need to sync two subversion repositories using only client libs. Repository A will contain commits that need to be synced to Repository B on a weekly basis. Repository B will not contain any changes. I do have server access to Repo A but not to Repo B.

As I can't access the server on Repo B using svndump is not an option.

I think it should be possible to write a script that uses the svn command line client but would rather use an existing solution. The commits don't need to contain the user information but the commit message and any properties that are set.

Any tools out there that might help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use svnsync to keep a repository "clone" on a system:

http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/10

No need to have physical access to the server to use "svnadmin dump".

Comment: Ok, to be more precise: I don't have any shell access to the server Repo B is running on. As far as I know svnadmin only works on local filesystems but not on remote repositories?

Comment: I just told you...you don't need shell access when using svnsync.  Read the article then come back with questions/comments.

Comment: I think this would help me if I don't have access to Repo A. Repo B needs a pre-revprop-change hook which I can't install. Am I wrong? Thanks for the hint anyway

Comment: Make yourself the "bridge".  You have a local repo that you clone via svnsync from a.  You can then push those changes to Repo B however you like.  You can even do cross-repository merging that will not require any intermediary.

Comment: Accepted as we got our customer to install the hook. Thanks for your help!